# Define conversion operator only for some template specializations: expected a type / expected type-specifier

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, implicit-conversion, template-specialization, conversion-operator

```c
template<int a>
class A {};
operator A<0>::bool() {
    return true;
}

// Goal:
bool b1 = A<0>();   // Allow
//bool b2 = A<1>(); // Error
```

CLion gives the error "Expected a type" on the second `A`. GCC gives the error "expected type-specifier" on `A<0>`. This gives a similar error when `typename` is used instead of `int`. Why, and how can I only define a conversion for some template specializations?

#### Version info:

C++ 20, CLion 2019.1.4, CMake 3.14.3, GCC 8.3.0, Debian 8.3.0-6

Comment: This code only remotely resembles C++. It makes little sense, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My use case is typed units, where unitless values can be implicitly converted to (and from) the underlying `double`. (The template arguments are the exponents on the types of units, so `Value<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>` should be implicitly converted to `double`, but no other `Value` should.)

Comment: You may be looking for something [like this](https://rextester.com/UPUH84896)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! Feel free to write your own answer and/or copy mine (with or without giving me credit)!

Answer (score 1):

You might use SFINAE for this:

```
template<int a>
class A {
public:
    template<int B = a, class = std::enable_if_t<B == 0>>
    operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to move the operator keyword to after the double colon: `A<0>:: operator bool()`, and add `template<>` before the definition. The class should declare it as a normal operator method. Thanks to [this link](https://rextester.com/UPUH84896) [posted by Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121535/define-conversion-operator-only-for-some-template-specializations-expected-a-ty#comment100761059_57121535).